# Configuration-only deploy of WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, iis

We run a web application with many (50+) WCF service hosts (Written in C#, running on Win 2008R2/IIS 7.5) for integration with different external vendors. We would like to add another service to each of these hosts for administration. This service can be generic enough that we have a single service definition which we define in some library which we can reference from the integration projects. But is there a way of actually adding the endpoint only in configuration? That is, I would like to avoid adding a .svc file, and only add some rows in the `web.config` service-section.

I tried adding this to the `web.config`:

```
<service name="Contracts.AdminService">
  <endpoint address="AdminService" contract="Contracts.IAdminService" binding="basicHttpBinding" />
</service>
```

This does not work however. If I add a simple `.svc` file like below it works

```
<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="Contracts.AdminService" CodeBehind="Contracts.AdminService.cs" %>
```

However, I would really like to avoid this so that it is less likely that a mistake is made when setting up a new host (we already do a bunch of automatic stuff with the config file, so adding a new service would be trivial). Is this possible? Any drawbacks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer myself after a while. The solution is WCF 4's [*file-less activation*](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee358764.aspx). This let me just add this to my `web.config`:

```
<serviceHostingEnvironment aspNetCompatibilityEnabled="true"
    multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true">
  <serviceActivations>
    <add relativeAddress="AdminService.svc" service="Contracts.AdminService"/>
  </serviceActivations>
</serviceHostingEnvironment>
```

After this I can access the service by going to `http://<hostname>/<path>/AdminService.svc`.

Answer (score -1):

WCF services are hosted in a [ServiceHost](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.servicehost.aspx).

ServiceHosts must be manually created when you are not hosting your WCFs in IIS/WAS, as both IIS/WAS interact with the ServiceHost on your behalf.

What you are basically doing inside the .svc file in IIS is instantianting a new ServiceHost.

Because ServiceHost can only host a single service type, if you plan on creating new types of services for adminsitration, you will need a service host for each of those new types.

So, the short answer to your questions is that you can't just add some information in your web.config for the new services you are going to create, you also need a mechanism to instantiate a ServiceHost.

Comment: Actually, it seems fileless activation can do this, see my post. Are we discussing different things?

Comment: Nope. I just didn't know about file-less activation. Thanks